# A class to calculate the range of a car in java

Tags: java

So I'm working on homework but I keep getting a return value warning in 
addGas() and drive(). But, even when add return statements I either get a wrong answer or NaN. This is my first programming class in Java so I'm assuming that where my trouble is, is in understanding so please explain, instead of just giving the fix! thank you!

> My Car class:

```
public class Car
{
    // instance variables - replace the example below with your own
    private double milesPerGallon;
    private double fuel;

    /**
     * Constructor for objects of class Car
     */
    public Car(double milesPerGallon)
    {
        // initializes all instance varibles to starting values
        this.milesPerGallon = milesPerGallon;
        //set gas to initial 3.5
        fuel = 3.5;
    }

    /**
     * adding gass to instance variable 
     */
    public double addGas(double fuel) // takes one parameter from tester, the amount of gas to add to the tank
    {
        // increases the amount of gas in the tank 
        this.fuel = this.fuel + fuel;
    }

    /**
     * What is the remaining gas? 
     */
    public double drive(double distance) // takes one parameter from tester, the distence in miles that were driven
    {
        // calculating the gas
        // decreases the amount of gas in the tank
        double leftOverFuel = fuel * milesPerGallon - distance;
        //distance
        fuel = (distance / milesPerGallon);
        // update the instance variabl
    }

    /**
     * When will the car get empty fuel?
     */
    public double range()
    {
        // calculates range, the number of miles the car can travel until the gas tank is empty
        double leftOverFuel;
        leftOverFuel = fuel * milesPerGallon;
        // returns the calculations 
        return leftOverFuel;
    }

}
```

> the CarTester class:

```
public class CarTester
{
    /**
     * main() method
     */
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Car honda = new Car(30.0);      // 30 miles per gallon

        honda.addGas(9.0);              // add 9 more gallons
        honda.drive(210.0);             // drive 210 miles

        // print range remaining
        System.out.println("Honda range remaining: " + honda.range());

        Car toyota = new Car(26.0);      // 26 miles per gallon

        toyota.addGas(4.5);              // add 4.5 more gallons
        toyota.drive(150.0);             // drive 150 miles

        // print range remaining
        System.out.println("Toyota range remaining: " + toyota.range());
    }
}
```

Comment: your `drive` method looks totally wrong to me. You should calculate how much fuel you've used, and remove that from the quantity of fuel.

Comment: @tannar Take a look at the answer I provided. And if it helped you, mark the answer as accepted by clicking on the hollow tick next to the answer. When you accept an answer, your rep increases too! :)

Answer (score 2):

Change the return types from both `drive()` and `addGas()` from `double` to `void`.

Change the method signatures like this:

```
public void addGas(double fuel) {
    this.fuel = this.fuel + fuel;   
}

public void drive(double distance) {
    double leftOverDistance = fuel * milesPerGallon - distance;
    this.fuel = (leftOverDistance / milesPerGallon);
}
```

#### Explanation:

The reason why you were getting **add return statements** error is you have defined the methods to be returning `double` values, but you haven't returned anything.

In your particular case, return statements are not useful. In `addGas`, you are adding the `fuel` passed as argument to the field `this.fuel`, so nothing to return. In `drive()` you are setting a new calculated value for the field `this.fuel`, again nothing to return. Hence void return type is the justified return type for these methods.

By the way, your `drive()` method seems to have wrong logic. Check my version.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing that is just a syntax error is in your drive() and addGas(). You are setting the return  type as a double, but not returning anything. Here is the fix:

```
public void addGas(double gas){/*Code Here*/} // Void means that there won't return value
public void drive(double distance){/*Code Here*/} // Same as addGas()
```

Another thing i noticed, which isn't too big of an issue, but my OCD makes me have to tell you, when you are removing gas from your tank in the drive() method, you create a double named leftOverFuel that isn't used for anything. Also, you are setting your current level of fuel to MPG / distance which has absolutely no purpose. You want to subtract the amount being used from your current fuel. Try this:

```
public void drive(double distance){
    double fuelUsed = distance / milesPerGallon;
    fuel = fuel - fuelUsed;
}
```

I hope this helped! Thanks for the read.

Comment: Double check your logic. `fuelUsed` should by `distance/milesPerGallon`

Comment: truuuuuu srry may bad.

Answer (score 0):

/* you can also calculate a car value by using these classes. However, this method does not return a negative value.
*/

```
public class CarWorthSrv {

 public int carWorth (int year, int initVal, int mileage)
 {
    int currentYear=2016;
    final int DEP_VALUE = 1000;
    year = currentYear - year;
    double yearlyMileage = (mileage*1.0)/year;
    int value = initVal-DEP_VALUE;

    if(year==currentYear){
        value = value;
    }
    else if(year<currentYear){
        if(yearlyMileage>=10000&&yearlyMileage<=12000){
            value = value -(1400*year);
            if(value<0){
                value =0;
            }
        }
        else if(yearlyMileage>12000){
            value = value -(1550*year);
        }
        else if(yearlyMileage<10000){
            value = value -(1300*year);
        }
    }



    return value;
 }




 }
public class CarWorthDrv
 {
 public static void main(String[] args) {

    CarWorthSrv srvObj = new CarWorthSrv();

    System.out.println();
    System.out.print("Testing a 2009 vehicle.  Purchase price: $22,000 with  89,000 miles: ");
    int result = srvObj.carWorth(2009, 22000, 89000); 

    if (result == 10150)
        System.out.println("PASS");
    else
    {
        System.out.println("*** FAIL ***");
        System.out.println("should be 10150.  your method returned: " + result + "\n");
    }

    System.out.print("Testing a 2011 vehicle.  Purchase price: $29,000 with  54,500 miles: ");
    result = srvObj.carWorth(2011, 29000, 54500); 

    if (result == 21000)
        System.out.println("PASS");
    else
    {
        System.out.println("*** FAIL ***");
        System.out.println("should be 21000.  your method returned: " + result + "\n");
    }


    System.out.print("Testing a 2012 vehicle.  Purchase price: $34,400 with  24,700 miles: ");
    result = srvObj.carWorth(2012, 34400, 24700); 

    if (result == 28200)
        System.out.println("PASS");
    else
    {
        System.out.println("*** FAIL ***");
        System.out.println("should be 28200.  your method returned: " + result + "\n");
    }


    System.out.print("Testing a 2013 vehicle.  Purchase price: $32,000 with  30,000 miles: ");
    result = srvObj.carWorth(2013, 32000, 30000); 
    System.out.println( (result == 26800)? "PASS":"*** FAIL ***\nshould be 26800. Your method returned: " + result + "\n");

    System.out.print("Testing a 2014 vehicle.  Purchase price: $29,900 with  24,000 miles: ");
    result = srvObj.carWorth(2014, 29900, 24000); 
    System.out.println( (result == 26100)? "PASS":"*** FAIL ***\nshould be 26100. Your method returned: " + result + "\n");

    System.out.print("Testing a 2012 vehicle.  Purchase price: $28,900 with  48,002 miles: ");
    result = srvObj.carWorth(2012, 28900, 48002); 
    System.out.println( (result == 21700)? "PASS":"*** FAIL ***\nshould be 21700. Your method returned: " + result + "\n");

    System.out.print("Testing a 2016 vehicle.  Purchase price: $35,900 with   1,200 miles: ");
    result = srvObj.carWorth(2016, 35900, 1200); 
    System.out.println( (result == 34900)? "PASS":"*** FAIL ***\nshould be 34900. Your method returned: " + result + "\n");

    System.out.print("Testing a 1997 vehicle.  Purchase price: $19,000 with 210,000 miles: ");
    result = srvObj.carWorth(1997, 19000, 210000); 
    System.out.println( (result == 0)? "PASS":"*** FAIL ***\nshould be 0. Your method returned: " + result + "\n");

    System.out.print("Testing a 2002 vehicle.  Purchase price: $19,200 with 130,000 miles: ");
    result = srvObj.carWorth(2002, 19200, 130000); 
    System.out.println( (result == 0)? "PASS":"*** FAIL ***\nshould be 0. Your method returned: " + result + "\n");


    System.out.println();

 } //main 

 }
```